# Adding pagination to query for custom page

Tags: pagination

I've made a custom news page using a custom page template and this is my query for latest posts:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content(); ?>
        <div class="line2"></div>
    <?php endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!-- Start latest post -->
<?php $latest_post = get_posts( 'numberposts=5' ); // Defaults args fetch posts starting with the most recent
foreach( $latest_post as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="newsthumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="newstitle">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="postdate-category">
        <?php esportsheaven_posted_on(); ?> | <?php the_category(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="newscontent">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_query();
```

There should be 5 posts initially on the page and when the site gets more then 5 posts, I'm looking to add pagination. What's the best/most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to paginate the query in future, I recommend the following

- Changing to `WP_Query` instead as it is better suited for paginated queries.
- Although you still have less than 5 posts, you can make your query pagination ready by adding the `paged` parameter to your query
- Your use of `wp_reset_query()` is incorrect. That is used in conjuction with `query_posts` which you should never use. You should be using `wp_reset_postdata()`. Also, you don't need to reset the main query, it is already done.
- Just a tip, use curlies instead of `:` and `endif` and `endwhile`. It is easier to debug and almost all if not all code editors support this syntax

You can try something like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) { 
    while ( have_posts() ) { 
        the_post();

        the_content(); ?>
        <div class="line2"></div>
    <?php } 
}
?>

<!-- Start latest post -->
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$latest_post = new WP_Query( 'numberposts=5&paged=' . $paged ); // Defaults args fetch posts starting with the most recent
if ( $latest_post->have_posts() ) { 
        while ( $latest_post->have_posts() ) { 
            $latest_post->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="newsthumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="newstitle">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="postdate-category">
                <?php esportsheaven_posted_on(); ?> | <?php the_category(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="newscontent">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: wp_reset_query() is used in Genesis and there's no query_posts in Genesis.

Comment: It is stupid in my opinion, why are you resetting the main query to itself? Also, Genesis is never referenced. I pointed out to the OP that `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts`. It is maybe personal preference using it with the main query, but really, think about it, the main query sets the global scope values, why do you need to reset that globals to the main query if the main query was used to set it in the first place

Comment: I agree. Just don't know why people use it when not using query_posts.

Comment: Please let me know if this solution worked so that I can assist you if not. If my solution worked, please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer, it will go green. Thank you :-)

Comment: I actually figured out my own solution late last night, but it ran similar to this! This works for sure! Thanks man